# Is this condition on three polynomials sufficient for them not being coprime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, coprime

**Lemma:** Let $R$ be an integral domain, $f,g\in R[X]$. The following is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ and $g$ not to be coprime: There exist $s,t\in R[X]$ such that $1\le \deg s<\deg g$ and $1\le \deg t<\deg f$, while
$$fs+gt=0.$$
**Proof:** (necessary:) Suppose $f$ and $g$ share a factor $d$ with $\deg d >1$. Take $s=\frac gd$ and $t=-\frac td$.

(sufficient:) Suppose $s$ and $t$ exist as described, then $fs=-gt$. If $f$ and $g$ are coprime, then $f\mid t$ which contradicts $\deg t<\deg f$. Hence, $f$ and $g$ are not coprime. Q.E.D.

---

We can imitate the proof of the lemma to show that for $f,g,h\in R[X]$ not to be coprime, it is necessary that there exist $s,t,u\in R[X]$ with
$$ftu+gsu+hst=0$$
and
\begin{align*}
1&\le \deg s < \deg f\\
1&\le \deg t < \deg g\\
1&\le \deg u < \deg h.
\end{align*}

---

**Question:** Is the above condition sufficient for $f,g,h$ not to be coprime?

Answer (score 1):

The condition is not sufficient. Take for example
\begin{align*}
f&=X^2\\
g&=X^2+1\\
h&=-2X^2-1\\
s&=t=u=X,
\end{align*}
then clearly
\begin{align*}
1&\le \deg s < \deg f\\
1&\le \deg t < \deg g\\
1&\le \deg u < \deg h
\end{align*}
and
$$ftu + gsu + hst = X^2(x^2+X^2+1-2X^2-1)=0,$$
by $f,g,h$ are coprime over any $R[X]$.